# command-line args issue

Tags: java, command-line-arguments

```
public static void main(String[] args)  {
    String from = "";
    String to = "";
    String subject = "";
    String body = "";
    System.out.println("number of args : " + args.length);
    for (int i = 0; i < args.length; i++) {
        if (args[i].startsWith("From:")) {
            from = args[i].substring(5);
            System.out.println("MAIL FROM: " + from);
        } else if(args[i].startsWith("To:")) {
            to = args[i].substring(2);
            System.out.println("RCPT TO: " + to);
        } else if(args[i].startsWith("Subject:")) {
            subject = args[i];
            System.out.println("SUBJECT: " + subject.substring(8));
        } else if (args[i].startsWith("Body:")) { //The rest
            for (int j = i; j < args.length; j++) {
            body += args[j];
        }
        System.out.println(body);
    }
}
```

my  problem is length of args

when I enter this in command line :

```
 java test To:a@a.com From:b@b.com Subject:hi  Body:hi I see you
```

my  output is this:

```
number of args : 7
```

my expected output is like this :

```
number of args: 4
```

can I do something to exclude hi I see you from length of args? I don't want to use quotes.

Comment: Change the order of your args.

Comment: Add spaces, since body += args[j]; removes any

Comment: I don't want to change the order of my args but I want to mail from comes first

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the spacing, change:

```
body += args[j];
```

to...

```
body += args[j] + " ";
```

then to get the FROM field to show up first, have another for loop before the one you wrote, where it only checks for the FROM field. It will print that, then the other loop will catch and print the rest! :)

Answer (score 2):

It's much easier if you just wrap your message in quotes:

```
java test To:a@a.com From:b@b.com Subject:hi  Body: "hi I see you"
```

Now, you know that the next argument after `"Body:"` will always be the full text. Otherwise, if you want to keep them connected:

```
java test To:a@a.com From:b@b.com Subject:hi  "Body:hi I see you"
```

Again, the argument that begins with `"Body:"` will contain the full text, except now it has the `"Body:"` at the beginning, so strip it out with `substring()` like you have been doing.

The only downside to this is if your message actually contains double quotes, which you will need to escape with `\"`. However, you'd have to do this for the shell you're executing in anyway, so it shouldn't be that much of a problem.

Comment: I know, but here i don't want to use quotes for body, as you can see in my code I'm doing it by loop. but I want to separate spaces in my body

Comment: @jamesb - One problem with that is you'll get inconsistent messages. For example, if I wrote `Hello{space}{space}World`, without the quotes, you'll never be able to detect that I entered two spaces. IMO you're making it harder on yourself without using the quotes `:)`